# How to return an image's size (resolution) in Cognex In-Sight Explorer (Speadsheet)?

Tags: spreadsheet, cognex

This may be a dumb question, but is there a way to return an image's size (Length and Width) in Cognex insight explorer spreadsheet? I am somewhat familiar with this software and was hoping to use some form of `GetMaxRow()` on `AquireImage()`, but this does not work. I've spent an hour searching through the help docs and can't seem to find what I'm looking for. There has to be an easy function for returning the image resolution (row and col), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of **In-Sight Explorer** are you using?

Here is what has worked for me ever since **In-Sight Explorer v4.9.3**:

- Image Row: `GetRow(A0)`
- Image Column: `GetCol(A0)`
- Image Height: `GetHigh(A0)`
- Image Width: `GetWide(A0)`

Where `A0` is your AcquireImage() cell

If you're using a newer camera that uses **In-Sight Vision Suite**:

- Image X: `GetX(A0)`
- Image Y: `GetY(A0)`
- Image Height: `GetHeight(A0)`
- Image Width: `GetWidth(A0)`

Where `A0` is your AcquireImage() cell

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the `GetWide()` and `GetHigh()` functions work with `AquireImage()`, but not `GetRow()`.

Comment: Indeed, the `GetRow()` and `GetCol()` functions are used to retrieve results like points from a `FindLine` tool or so, you're right to use `GetHigh()` and `GetWide()`